# SUMMARIZECOLUMNS GROUPBY and SUM issue

Tags: dax

Hope someone can help me.

Here's my DAX query:

```
Resource Allocations =
VAR AssignedCapacityWeighted =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            'Project Resources'[ResourceId],
            'Project Resources'[Assigned End Date].[Year],
            'Project Resources',
            "Assigned Capacity Weighted", SUM ( 'Project Resources'[Assigned Capacity Weighted] ),
            "Year", MIN ( 'Project Resources'[Assigned End Date].[Year] )
        ),
        "ResourceId", 'Project Resources'[ResourceId] & " ",
        "Assigned Capacity Weighted", [Assigned Capacity Weighted],
        "Year", [Year]
    )
VAR ChapterTeamsFullName =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        'Teams (People)',
        "Id", 'Teams (People)'[Id],
        "ResourceId", 'Teams (People)'[Id] & " ",
        "Chapter", 'Teams (People)'[Chapter],
        "Team", 'Teams (People)'[Team],
        "Full Name", 'Teams (People)'[Full Name]
    )
VAR ResourceAllocationParts =
    NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN ( ChapterTeamsFullName, AssignedCapacityWeighted )
RETURN
    ResourceAllocationParts
```

Output looks like this:
[image]

For some reason it's not summarising if I include Year. Taking Year out works perfectly! Someone please help.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` does not have *row context* but only *filter context*, therefore the "Year" measure you calculate using `MIN ( 'Project Resources'[Assigned End Date].[Year] )` returns a constant value, which is not the year in the current row, but the minimum of the whole table.

In your case, since you just want the year (which is already present in the source table, and use as grouping column) you can use that without additional calculations

```
VAR AssignedCapacityWeighted =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            'Project Resources'[ResourceId],
            'Project Resources'[Assigned End Date].[Year],
            'Project Resources',
            "Assigned Capacity Weighted", SUM ( 'Project Resources'[Assigned Capacity Weighted] ),
        "ResourceId", 'Project Resources'[ResourceId] & " ",
        "Assigned Capacity Weighted", [Assigned Capacity Weighted],
        "Year", 'Project Resources'[Assigned End Date].[Year]
    )
```

Another possible way, which should work (I'm not sure given the absence of row context) is to wrap you "year" calculation in `CALCULATE` to force context transition

```
"Year", CALCULATE(MIN ( 'Project Resources'[Assigned End Date].[Year] ))
```

I'm curious about the `CALCULATE` behavior, can you let me know if it works?